# Why do I get erroneous form element names when rendering a collection in EditorTemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

In my current project I have a several instances of view models that are contain a collection of children view models, like so:

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Children = new List<ChildViewModel>();
    }

    public List<ChildViewModel> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

The data in the child view model is such that it can be used in both a create and update form. With this in mind, I have been attempting to use EditorFor to generate the form elements for these collections of child view models.

I know that if create a EditorTemplate and simply feed the collection into the EditorFor like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(vm => vm.Children)
```

that EditorFor will automatically iterate over the collection and apply the EditorTemplate to each individual item. The problem I've run into is that should I wish to take certain actions on every three items, render two items into the same table row, or some other variant of this I need to force EditorFor to use a specific EditorTemplate, which is fine except for a curious issue that arises.

Here is my test EditorTemplate

```
@model List<Sandbox.Models.ChildViewModel>

<table>
@for(int i = 0, j = 1; i < Model.Count - 1; i+=2)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[i].Age)
        </td>
        @if(j < Model.Count)
        {
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o[j].Age)
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

and the view that contains the EditorFor call

```
@model Sandbox.Models.ParentViewModel

<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @using(Html.BeginForm()) {
                @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Children, "ChildrenTemplate")
                <input type="submit" />
            }
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When the form is generated using the above EditorTemplate, the form elements generated by the EditorTemplate have malformed name attributes. Where they should be

```
Children[1].Age
```

they are instead

```
Children.[1].Age
```

This throws the model binder completely out of whack and it will refuse to repopulate the parent view model on form submission.

The only way I have been able to resolve this is to make the model of the EditorTemplate be the parent view model instead of a list of child view models, which strongly limits my ability to use the template as while I might have several locations where I have the same collection of child view models, I don't have the same parent model containing it.

At this point, I know of the following options:

1. Change the model of the EditorTemplate to the parent view model, which limits by ability to reuse the template.
2. Create a custom model binder or action filter to try and clean the form names before the model binder can see the problem.
3. Figure out how to make the current setup work.

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could little change your code as like

the view that contains the EditorFor call

```
<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Children[i]) //also you could mention the template name
    }
</table>
```

Here is my test EditorTemplate

```
@model Sandbox.Models.ChildViewModel

    <tr>
        <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Name)
        </td>            
        <td>
             @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.Age)
        </td>            
    </tr>
```

For more details 
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Answer (score 0):

In your `ChildrenTemplate.cshtml`:

```
@model List<Sandbox.Models.ChildViewModel>
<table>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
</table>
```

and then define an editor template which will automatically be rendered for each element of the collection (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ChildViewModel.cshtml`):

```
@model Sandbox.Models.ChildViewModel
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    </td>            
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Age)
    </td>            
</tr>
```

This way you don't need to write any loops in your code and you don't have to worry about wrong names for your input fields. It works by convention.